# Sort by date and time not working in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm creating report with *Visual Studio 2013*. I need to sort data by 2 columns `Date` in descending order and `Time` in descending order (to get newest records in top). Stored Procedure returning correctly sorted data, but in Report It's randomly sorted.

I've tried to go in `Tablix Properties` > `Sorting` > Specify both columns `Date` and `Time` > Order `Z-A`, but nothing happens after I add this sorting, data stay in the same order.

Have you any ideas? Maybe that because I have added `Row Group` on some columns (including `Date` and `Time` columns)?

---

My data **for now** in report looks like (I provide It just for example):

```
Lisa  2015-04-21  10:20:06  Item1
John  2015-04-21  10:25:30  Item2
Peter 2015-03-18  13:35:32  Item3
Ralf  2015-04-03  09:26:52  Item4
```

---

And It **should be** (newest records in top):

```
John  2015-04-21  10:25:30  Item2
Lisa  2015-04-21  10:20:06  Item1
Ralf  2015-04-03  09:26:52  Item4
Peter 2015-03-18  13:35:32  Item3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your SSRS Report configuration it's difficult to give a definitive answer. The question I would ask would be why are you storing the `DATE` and `TIME` portions separately when you could just use a `DATETIME`?

One possible solution could be to combine the values into a  `DATETIME` value before returning the results and the sorting may behave.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DateVal) + CONVERT(DATETIME, TimeVal) CombinedDateTime
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

**Sample:**

This assumes that you are using SQL `DATE` and `TIME` data types on your columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Name] varchar(5), [DateVal] date, [TimeVal] time, [Item] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Name], [DateVal], [TimeVal], [Item])
VALUES
    ('Lisa', '2015-04-21', '10:20:06', 'Item1'),
    ('John', '2015-04-21', '10:25:30', 'Item2'),
    ('Peter', '2015-03-18', '13:35:32', 'Item3'),
    ('Ralf', '2015-04-03', '09:26:52', 'Item4')
;

SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, DateVal) + CONVERT(DATETIME, TimeVal) CombinedDateTime
FROM #Table1
ORDER BY CombinedDate DESC 

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

Comment: I mean sorting not working at all in report, I've tried this method to sort data by combined datetime, but seems that not working sorting in SSRS. My procedure returning good sorting in any way (If I combine date time or trying to order date and time separately)

Comment: The easiest option, as discussed, is to have a combined date and time field in your dataset. This can be included in your tablix but not visible. One more point, have you tried deleting your cached data ?

Comment: I just found issue, just don't know how to resolve It. That because here are some grouped rows. If I add Sorting to row's expression by any of grouped value It not working (date, time both are grouped) If I'm trying to sort with any value which isn't grouped It working, but I need to change sorting with grouped value...

Answer (score 0):

Are your dates sorted in date format? If they are coming from your data source as text for any reason you may be able to solve this by converting the text string to a date

e.g.
`=DateSerial(left(Fields!Date.Value,4),mid(Fields!Date.Value,4,2),right(Fields!Date.Value,2))`

as your sort expression would extract year, month and day from the text and convert to a date in SSRS.

A more optimal solution in this case, however, would be to fix your datasource so dates and times came through as dates and times.

Another possible problem is that you are changing the sort expression for the *tablix*, do you not want to enter a sort expression for the *group*? If you right click on the group and select group properties, you can add sorting for the individual group rather than the tablix.